# open recent files in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I recently upgraded my emacs (version 24.3), but i lost a function that was very convenient, and could not figure out the solution easily by google, so i wish i can get help here (which is always the case when i have problems with computer)

i remember my emacs can find recent file even the file is not in current editing folder. 
e.g., i am editing fileA in pathA, and i want to open a fileB that is in PathB/, i just press C-x C-f,  type fileB, emacs automaticall find the fileB in PathB, and auto-complete the full path to fileB in the  mini buffer. Dont know what package enables such function but it was there before my upgrading.

thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is library `recentf.el`, which comes with Emacs.  See, for example, command `recentf-open-files`.

But be aware that other, more general-purpose libraries can sometimes extend `recentf.el` features, making them more useful.

- One such is [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) multi-command [`icicle-recent-file`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input#VisitRecentFiles).
- Another is Icicles multi-command [`icicle-buffer`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Buffer-Name_Input) (`C-x b` by default), which can include recently visited files (with their paths) as candidates for buffer switching.  `C-x R` during completion toggles whether such candidates are included.

Comment: i know what you mean, but that is not what i am asking for, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

this is the key to the issue:

```
(setq ido-auto-merge-work-directories-length 0)
```

thanks to all anyway

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using `ido`, try turn on `ido-use-virtual-buffers`.

```
(setq ido-use-virtual-buffers t)
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work, yeah, i believe it is ido's settings, as i saw one comments on masteringemacs.org saying: "There is something in ido-mode that does something similar already. Press C-x C-f, type the file name (even though you’re in the wrong directory), wait a second and it pops up the correct directory (it has its own cache separate from recentf)."

Comment: well, i finally figured out it was (setq ido-auto-merge-work-directories-length 0)